# If a function is $n$ times continuously differentiable, prove that there are polynomals with grade lower then n with following conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, differential

I had this question.
Let's say that there is a function and it's $n$ times continuously differentiable. Take a random $a$ from $\Bbb R$ and $\delta$>0. Prove that there are polynomials $p$ and $q$ with degree lower than or equal to $n$ and a $m$ from $\Bbb R$ so that:
$p(x)\le f(x)\le q(x)$ and $q(x)-p(x)\le m(|x-a|)^{n}$ for $x$ in $[a,a+\delta[$.

I thought maybe I can use Taylor. Is there someone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Since $f^{(n)}$ is continuous, it has a minimum and a maximum on $[a,a+\delta]$. We can use this fact and Taylor's theorem to bound $f(x)$ by polynomials of degree $n$ from above and below.

Comment: Yeah i thought for p(x)=f(a) but for q(x) i'm struggeling. I can't prove that the second condition will be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a$ and $\delta>0$, and define
\begin{align}
P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k\,.
\end{align}
By Taylor's theorem, for each $x\in[a,a+\delta]$, there exists $\xi_x\in[a,x]$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x)=P(x)+\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi_x)}{n!}(x-a)^n\,.
\end{align}
Let $A$ and $B$ be the minimum and maximum of $f^{(n)}$ on $[a,a+\delta]$ respectively. Put
\begin{align}
p(x)&=P(x)+A(x-a)^n/n!\,, \\
q(x)&=P(x)+B(x-a)^n/n!\,.
\end{align}
Then $p$ and $q$ have the desired properties.